# Does glGenerateMipmap perform its averaging in linear space for sRGB textures?

Tags: opengl, mipmaps, srgb

The OpenGL 3.3 specification does not seem to ask that the mipmap generation be done in linear space.  All I can find is the following:

> The internal formats of the derived mipmap arrays all match those of
>   the levelbase array, and the dimensions of the derived arrays follow
>   the requirements described in section 3.8.14. The contents of the
>   derived arrays are computed by repeated, filtered reduction of the
>   levelbase array. For one- and two-dimensional array textures, each
>   layer is filtered independently. No particular filter algorithm is
>   required, though a box filter is recommended as the default filter.

I understand that the result of calling glGenerateMipMap is in sRGB if the original image is in sRGB and I have no problem with that.  But what happens in-between?  Surely we do not want to average colors that are on a log scale.  Is that implementation-specific?

Comment: I'd just like to point out that my AMD Radeon HD 7950 card seems not to do this in linear space.  It may be a driver issue.  To be on the safe side, I generate my mipmaps on the CPU for sRGB textures.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The relevant answer can be found in the OpenGL specification section 3.8.17:

> ### 3.8.17 sRGB Texture Color Conversion
>
> If the currently bound texture’s internal format is one of SRGB,SRGB8,SRGB_ALPHA,
>   SRGB8_ALPHA8, COMPRESSED_SRGB, or COMPRESSED_SRGB_ALPHA,
>   the red, green, and blue components are **converted from an sRGB color space to a
>   linear color space as part of filtering** described in sections **3.8.11** and *3.8.12*. Any
>   alpha component is left unchanged. Ideally, implementations should perform this
>   color conversion on each sample prior to filtering but implementations are allowed

Mipmap generation is described in section 3.8.11 and hence is subject to color space linearization.